# jpg image <image> in SVG file gets resized mistakenly on some iPads

Tags: image, ipad, svg, jpeg, raster

What can I do about a jpg image within an `<image>` tag in an SVG file, getting wrongly resized on an iPad Mini?

I have a webpage which includes a complex SVG file. This SVG contains a jpg image (raster) as an `<image>` tag (which serves as a background), along with many `<circle>` and `<text>` elements (vector). On some iPads the jpg image gets resized improperly, out of synch with the vector elements which display correctly. On a computer or iPhone it is displaying correctly.

[edit: See below note about which models have problems...]

The whole thing is meant to be scaled up and down so people can zoom in and out, and the vector elements resize with the background raster image. Only on the iPad are they not displaying correctly.

Models:

iPad 1 (and 2?): OK
iPad Air 1: OK
iPad Air 2: Image problem

iPad Mini 1: Image problem
iPad Mini 2: OK
iPad Mini 3: Image problem

Compare how this works on a computer versus problematic versions of iPad:
http://bestofyourtown.com/test/

HTML:

```
<div class="mapplic-map-image">
<svg 
    xml:space="preserve" 
    enable-background="new 0.5 890.5 5954 3705" 
    viewBox="0.5 890.5 5954 3705" 
    y="0px" 
    x="0px" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    id="layer_1" version="1.1">
<image 
    transform="matrix(1 0 0 1.0002 0.4971 890.498)" 
    xlink:href="http://bestofyourtown.com/svgbgs/downtown-high.jpg" 
    id="downtown-4-mapplic_1_" 
    height="3705" width="5954" overflow="hidden">
</image>
<g id="shopping">
<a xlink:href="#56" id="_x35_6">
    <circle r="43.718" cy="2189.552" cx="4243.234" id="_x35_6_1_"/>
    <text font-size="49.9635" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 4215.4473 2207.2461)">56</text>
</a>
<a xlink:href="#79n" id="_x37_9n">
    <circle r="43.718" cy="3000.219" cx="4147.234" id="_x37_9"/>
    <text font-size="49.9635" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 4119.4473 3017.9131)">79</text>
</a>
[etc...]
</g>
<g id="attractions">
<a xlink:href="#59" id="_x35_9">
    <circle r="43.718" cy="1789.844" cx="4197.435" id="_x35_9_1_"/>
    <text font-size="49.9635" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 4169.6484 1807.3281)">59</text>
</a>
<a xlink:href="#107" id="_x31_07">
    <circle r="43.718" cy="1897.855" cx="1406.146" id="_x31_07_1_"/>
    <text font-size="49.9635" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1362.3594 1916.3389)">107</text>
</a>
[etc…]
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: What pixel size is the image?

Comment: It is large; height="3705" width="5954". Most of it overflows its container, and you drag it too see different parts of the image.